# "AssetsPackManifest.plist" couldn't be removed

Tags: ios, xcode

In Xcode 10, when preparing archive of app for distrubrion Ad-Co, happens an error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbrfR.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. delete the plist file from BuildPhases -> Copy bundle resources -> AssetsPackManifest.plist
2. Try to clean your project (Cmd+Shift+K)
   and, try to build your project.
   This can be one of solution.